# databricks throws OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported when appending to azure blob file

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

Doing some file manipulation on databricks and it's failing due to the following error when using `open('\mnt\file\','a')`

```
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported
```

however, it will succeed if `open('\mnt\file\','w')`.
How can "a" not be supported on azure blob? Any workaround here?

Comment: Do I need to create the file locally on databricks and move it to blob once it's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the files in Azure blob storage are immutable, which means you can not append them. but you can overwrite it which will rewrite the file after the changes.

```
Example Python code

`file_path = '/mnt/file/'  # Your Azure Blob storage mount path

# Read the existing data
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    existing_data = file.read()

# Modify the existing_data as needed
modified_data = existing_data + "New data to append"

# Write the modified data back to the file, effectively overwriting it
with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
    file.write(modified_data)
```

`

Answer (score 1):

It's one of the [limitations of local file API](https://docs.databricks.com/en/files/index.html#local-file-api-limitations), primarily because it's a limitation of cloud storage.  If you need to perform append operation, copy file from DBFS to the local disk, append the data and copy file to DBFS.

```
local_file = "/tmp/copy.file"
dbfs_file = "dbfs:/....."
dbutils.fs.cp(dbfs_file, f"file:{local_file}")
with open(local_file, "a") as file:
   ....
dbutils.fs.cp(f"file:{local_file}", dbfs_file)
```